# Python Serial Readline() vs Readlines()

Tags: python

I need to use some At commands & read the data for that I am using below cmds , the response I would be getting is in multiple lines

```
serialPort.write(b"AT+CMD\r\n")
time.sleep(1)
response = serialPort.readlines()
```

if I am using only readline() i dont get full expected response but if i do read lines()  i do get the full data but some lines skipped sometime , i need to know the difference between these 2 methods & also  for the

> timeout flag

how does it effects functionality of these

Answer (score 2):

`readline()`: reads one line, if you use multiple times, each time it will keep giving next line until it reaches end of file or file is closed.

`readlines()`: returns a list of lines from a file

If you want the output of a whole file, you can use `read()` instead.

About the `timeout` flag, I don't think timeout flag exists for I/O operations in Python? But if you are talking about the one in `Serial`, then it specifies the maximum time to wait for serial data.